# CSS How to center properly

Tags: html, css

I just cloned the a project and modified it but the centering of my logo does not work properly. When the side bar is unfolded my logo is centered properly but when its folded its not.

[Unfolded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxA42.png), [Folded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts3AV.png)

Git link: [Responsive Glass Sidebar using CSS and JavaScript](https://github.com/hosseinnabi-ir/Responsive-Glass-Sidebar-using-CSS-and-JavaScript)

I want to be able to view the div and center the logo in the sidebar when its unfolded and folded.

```css
.display {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  Hello world
</div>
```

Comment: check size of your small logo, i think your logo has extra size

Comment: @PetePearl No, also happens with the original.

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: center;` to your CSS, like below. And by the way, that also works on `<img>` tags, when they are inside a `<div>` element.

```css
.display {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  Hello world
</div>
```

And if you want the background coloring to be only the length of the text, use a `<span>` tag:

```css
.display {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"> Hello world </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add text-align:center to your css

```css
.display {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  Hello world
</div>
```